# Kotlin - How to get object value using loop?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
data class StatusObject(val label: String, val value: Int)

object OrderStatus {

    val inTray = StatusObject("In tray", 0)
    val paymentPending = StatusObject("Payment Pending", 1)
    val paymentDone = StatusObject("Payment Done", 2)
    val completed = StatusObject("Completed", 3)
    val cancelled = StatusObject("Cancelled", 4)

}

fun findStatusLable(statusObject: Objects, value: Int) {
}
```

I am new to Kotlin, and trying to work on a small app. The function `findStatusLable` should return the label when provided the name of data object, and a numeric value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please correct any syntax mistakes.

Comment: as i said, im new to this, i have tried googling, i come from JS background, this is an attempt without much time to complete.  here is my js code.
`export const findStatus = (container, value) => Object.values(container).find(status => status.value === value);`

Comment: the best thing to do when working with a new language is to read some of the documentation. You will find for example that `object` is not what you want to use here, and there are some builtin functions that do what you are asking for here, given that you represent the data in a proper way

Comment: @TimCastelijns, there is a specific reason why i chose object. and i'm sure about that. please let me know if there anyway. thanks.

Comment: given the code you posted I am fairly certain you chose wrong. Could you share a bit more about what you are working on and why you think `object` is the right pick for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182418/discussion-between-manjunath-hegde-and-tim-castelijns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve. But if you want to get `label` of a `StatusObject` by `value` than I can suggest to use `enum`, like this:

```
enum class OrderStatus(val label: String, val code: Int) {
    IN_TRAY("In tray", 0),
    PAYMENT_PENDING("Payment Pending", 1),
    PAYMENT_DONE("Payment Done", 2),
    COMPLETED("Completed", 3),
    CANCELLED("Cancelled", 4);

    companion object {

        fun findStatusLabel(code: Int): String {
            return values().firstOrNull { it.code == code }?.label ?: ""
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could do something like:

```
OrderStatus.findStatusLabel(4) // Will return Cancelled
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, again this solves half of my problem.
this is what i'm trying achieve

 `OrderStatus.IN_TRAY.code` and `OrderStatus.findStatusLabel(4)`
it needs to be accessible in both cases. my code failed in finding label, this fails in other case.

Comment: @ManjunathHegde, But it is accessible in both places, isn't it? You can get `label` with `findStatusLabel` method or you can directly get it from a `OrderStatus` object.